# Существование объектов в JS

Tags: javascript

Вот небольшой скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var fooObject = function(elementsArr,...)
  {
     this.elements = elementsArr
     this.  ...
     ...
  };
  fooObject.prototype = {
     fooMethod:{
        ...
     }
     ...
  };
  function doIt()
  {
     var fooInstance = new fooObject(document.getElementsByClassName("foo-class"));
     //----
     //Тут что-нибудь делаем с fooInstance 
     //----
  }
  ...
  doIt();

</script>
```

Вопрос в том: после выполнения функции **doIt** - экземпляр **fooInstance** будет продолжать существовать в памяти? или уничтожится независимо от того что есть ссылки на dom элементы?

Comment: Не забывайте про замыкания!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я конечно не на 100%, уверен но думаю что все локальные переменные и аргументы функции уничтожаются после выхода из неё